# how to create SQL tables

Tags: sql, r

[image]

QUESTION: Using SQL create a table genres with columns genre_id and genre_name, and make genre_id a primary key on the table. Ensure that genre_id is defined as integer type and genre_name as a character/text.

ATTEMPTED ANSWER:

```
CREATE TABLE name(
  genre_id   INTEGER,
  genre_name    TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY(genre_id)
)
```

Error: table name already exists
Failed to execute SQL chunk

Comment: Set `genre_id = INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: I'm a little confused ... `table name already exists` means that the table exists and you cannot "create" it again. Once created, a table exists until (a) you explicitly call `drop table`; or (b) the database is reset and _all_ tables are dropped. (The exception would be temporary tables, but you're not doing that, so not a factor.)

Answer (score 1):

you have a typo genre_id vs gender_id.
Here your query fixed:

```
CREATE TABLE name(
  genre_id   INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  genre_name    TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY(genre_id)
)
```

Comment: I made a change to the question.

Comment: Oh I see, I think name is a reserved keywords like user. Try with backquotes: ```CREATE TABLE `name`(
  genre_id   INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  genre_name    TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY(genre_id)
)```

Comment: it still comes up with Error: external pointer is not valid
Failed to execute SQL chunk

Comment: Your query is now good so the problem is not comming from that, I will need more context to solve this error.